# Is there a race condition in the `latch` sample in N3600?

Tags: c++, race-condition, language-lawyer, c++14

Proposed for inclusion in C++14 (aka C++1y) are some new thread synchronization primitives: latches and barriers.  The proposal is

- [N3600: C++ Latches and Barriers](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3600.html)
- [N3666: C++ Latches and Barriers, revised](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3666.html)

It sounds like a good idea and the samples make it look very programmer-friendly.  Unfortunately, I think the sample code invokes undefined behavior.  The proposal says of `latch::~latch()`:

> Destroys the latch. If the latch is destroyed while other threads are in `wait()`, or are invoking `count_down()`, the behaviour is undefined.

Note that it says "in `wait()`" and not "blocked in `wait()`", as the description of `count_down()` uses.

Then the following sample is provided:

> An example of the second use case is shown below. We need to load data and then process it using a number of threads. Loading the data is I/O bound, whereas starting threads and creating data structures is CPU bound. By running these in parallel, throughput can be increased.
>
> ```
> void DoWork()
> {
>     latch start_latch(1);
>     vector<thread*> workers;
>     for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
>       workers.push_back(new thread([&] {
>         // Initialize data structures. This is CPU bound.
>         ...
>         start_latch.wait();
>         // perform work
>         ...
>       }));
>     }
>     // Load input data. This is I/O bound.
>     ...
>     // Threads can now start processing
>     start_latch.count_down();
> }
> ```

Isn't there a race condition between the threads waking and returning from `wait()`, and destruction of the latch when it leaves scope?  Besides that, all the `thread` objects are leaked.  If the scheduler doesn't run all worker threads before `count_down` returns and the `start_latch` object leaves scope, then I think undefined behavior will result.  Presumably the fix is to iterate the vector and `join()` and `delete` all the worker threads after `count_down` but before returning.

1. Is there a problem with the sample code?
2. Do you agree that a proposal should show a complete correct example, even if the task is extremely simple, in order for reviewers to see what the use experience will be like?

---

Note: It appears possible that one or more of the worker threads haven't yet begun to wait, and will therefore call `wait()` on a destroyed latch.

---

Update: There's now a new version of the proposal, but the representative example is unchanged.

Comment: @stefan: I do not think that "release of blocked threads" includes "waiting for those threads to run at least until return from `wait()`"

Comment: Furthermore, it's possible that one of the threads hasn't even *reached` the `start_latch.wait()` call yet.

Comment: I agree with you. It seems that the example broken...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. Yes, I think that the sample code (which, in its defense, was intended to be concise) is broken. It should probably wait for the threads to finish.

Any implementation that allows threads to be blocked in wait() is almost certainly going to involves some kind of condition variable, and destroying the latch while a thread has not yet exited wait() is potentially undefined.

I don't know if there's time to update the paper, but I can make sure that the next version is fixed.

Alasdair

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for responding publicly.  It would be really great if you would follow up with a link to the next version when it becomes available.

Comment: There is an additional SG1 meeting in Santa Clara in July - I have posted an updated paper to the SG1 wiki, and I would expect it to be published (along with any other changes that come out of Santa Clara) in the pre-Chicago mailing.